# Wait functionality in Wget not working as expected

Tags: linux, wget, rhel

**Background:**
I am using wget (version 1.14-15.el7) on RedHat Linux (version 7.3 (Maipo)), in a Bash (version 4.2.46(1)) terminal.

Unfortunately, I am limited to this particular RHEL image, so I can't upgrade to a newer version of wget.

**Goal:**
I am trying to configure wget so that, if a download attempt fails, it does the following:
1) Retries the download 4 more times (total of 5 attempts)
2) Waits a FIXED amount of time (30 seconds) between download attempts ('retries')

For context, here is a relevant snippet of the wget manual:

```
   -w seconds
   --wait=seconds
       Wait the specified number of seconds between the retrievals.  Use of this option is
       recommended, as it lightens the server load by making the requests less frequent.
       Instead of in seconds, the time can be specified in minutes using the "m" suffix, in
       hours using "h" suffix, or in days using "d" suffix.

       Specifying a large value for this option is useful if the network or the destination
       host is down, so that Wget can wait long enough to reasonably expect the network error
       to be fixed before the retry.  The waiting interval specified by this function is
       influenced by "--random-wait", which see.

   --waitretry=seconds
       If you don't want Wget to wait between every retrieval, but only between retries of
       failed downloads, you can use this option.  Wget will use linear backoff, waiting 1
       second after the first failure on a given file, then waiting 2 seconds after the second
       failure on that file, up to the maximum number of seconds you specify.

       By default, Wget will assume a value of 10 seconds.
```

To be clear, I am using the `--wait` flag, NOT the `--waitretry` flag.

**Process:**

First, I export/set a wrong http_proxy and https_proxy, to ensure any download attempt will time out.

I run the following command:
`wget --tries=5 --wait=30 <url> -O <output_filename>`

At this point, the `--wait` functionality does NOT work as expected. Specifically, it does NOT wait 30s after each download attempt.

Instead:
1) After the first attempt, it waits 1s.
2) After the 2nd attempt, it waits 2s.
3) After the 3rd attempt, it waits 3s.
and so on ...

In other words, despite using the `--wait` flag (which should result in a fixed waiting time between download attempts), wget seems to be performing a 'linear backoff' as described in the `--waitretry` flag section.

**PROBLEM:**
I want the functionality of the `--wait` flag, NOT the `--waitretry` flag.

Unfortunately, the `--wait` flag seems to be acting like the `--waitretry` flag -- is there any way to get around this apparent bug in wget, so that using the `--wait` flag results in the expected fixed waiting time between download attempts?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: Thanks, I'll move it there.

Answer (score -1):

As can be seen in that `--help` dialog you provided, I believe you should be able to use `--waitretry` in your command, something like `get --tries=5 --waitretry=30 <url> -O <output_filename>` should work!

Comment: Thanks, but I actually do NOT want the functionality that `--waitretry` provides (where wget performs a linear backoff).  I'm looking for wget to wait a fixed amount of time between download attempts, which SHOULD be provided by the `--wait` flag but, for some reason, isn't working.

Comment: --`wait` is used kind of like a timeout, so that it waits for a response for x seconds, not as a sleep between tries. With --wait=30, it would send a request and wait up to 30 seconds before it fails due to timeout.